# Unable to execute TestNG Suite file via command line but works from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I have the following issue, I can run TestNG from Eclipse by right clicking the the testng.xml file, runs OK without problems.

When I try to execute it from the command line, I got the "[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: tests.HomePageTestCases" I tried to setting the path of the project folder and then setting the pathclas: 
set classpath = %ProjectPath%\target*;%ProjectPath%\src\test\java*

But still Im unable to run the test cases. I use eclipse ide with maven and TestNG, nothig else is installed.

I read a lot of post and all said the same on the project folder set the project and class path, but I cant make it work from command line, from eclipse is working fine.

I really burn all my ideas trying to figuring out what is the problem.

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/amitbhoraniya/TestNG-samples/tree/master/testng-simple) is a simple example of testng, please find a way to execute testng testcases via command line. Instead of running TestNG main class, build tool is better option.

Answer (score 0):

1. The immediate cause is that you didn't set properly the classpath. It should include at least `%ProjectPath%\target\classes` and `%ProjectPath%\target\test-classes`.
2. But don't lose your time with command-line formulas, because any build on a Maven project should be done **through the mvn tool**. In this case:

   `mvn test`